# Test sign in with slack button on an internal network

Tags: slack, slack-api

I have a slack app with a sign in with slack button. Earlier I was testing it on localhost with the redirect url as localhost.
Is there anyway I can test the same on an internal network, because right now every time I try to do that as soon as I authorise it redirects me to the localhost.(which it should since redirect url is localhost).

I tried to use the url of my internal network as the redirect url but it does not accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only redirect to an URL that is accessible from the public Internet. So you can't redirect to `localhost` or to a machine that is behind a company firewall and not reachable from the Internet.

To test your "Sign-in with Slack" button one good approach is to use a tool like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) that gives your a public URL and redirects traffic automatically to your local machine via VPN.

Also check [this tutorial](https://api.slack.com/tutorials/tunneling-with-ngrok) from Slack on how use ngrok.